# Assign a variable to an action input

Tags: javascript, post, action

I am trying to do a POST method with different actions depending on input.

My method looks like this

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="upload.php">
<p>Upload your .json file</p>
```

Now I have a function

```
function check(x) {

if (x===0){
  upload = "upload.php";
  console.log(upload);

} else if (x===1){
  upload = "upload_line.php";

} else if (x===2){
  upload = "upload_pie.php";

}else if (x===3){
  upload = "upload_round.php";

}else if (x===4){
  upload = "upload_bar2.php";

}else{
  upload = "upload.php";

}
```

}

check gets called with the onclick method of a radio button, so e.g.

```
<input onclick="check(0)" type="radio" name="options" id="pie" aria-label="Radio button for choosing Pie chart" autocomplete="off" checked>
```

thats assings a value to a variable.

Is it possible to use this variable in the action.

So e.g. if x = 1 i want to POST with action "upload_line.php"

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
Solution is to use `document.myForm.action = upload;` at the end of the function

```
  function check(x) {

  if (x===0){
    upload = "upload.php";
    console.log(upload);

  } else if (x===1){
    upload = "upload_line.php";
    console.log(upload);

  } else if (x===2){
    upload = "upload_pie.php";
    console.log(upload);

  }else if (x===3){
    upload = "upload_round.php";
    console.log(upload);

  }else if (x===4){
    upload = "upload_bar2.php";
    console.log(upload);

  }else{
    upload = "upload.php";

  }
```

document.myForm.action = upload;

}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

HTML

```
<form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="upload.php">
<p>Upload your .json file</p>
```

JS

```
function check( x ) {

  if ( x === 0 ) {
    upload = "upload.php";
    console.log(upload);
  } 
  else if ( x === 1 ) {
    upload = "upload_line.php";
  } 
  else if ( x === 2 ) {
    upload = "upload_pie.php";
  } else if ( x === 3 ) {
    upload = "upload_round.php";
  } else if ( x === 4 ) {
    upload = "upload_bar2.php";
  }
  else {
    upload = "upload.php";
  }

  // set the form's POST action.

  // Whoops! This should be
  // document.getElementById( "myForm" ).formAction = upload; 
  document.getElementById( "myForm" ).action = upload; 

}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately for some reason the action does not get changed. I tested the upload variable, it logs the choosen value, when submitted tho its still always upload.php

Comment: @kukgStone of course, because above code doesn't change form action.

Comment: thank you it works now with document.myForm.action = upload; instead of document.getElementById( "myForm" ).formAction = upload;

Comment: Yes, the code should actually have been "document.getElementById( "myForm" ).action = upload;". I have corrected it in my example above.